# PHP não está retornando dados ao AJAX para Validar Captcha

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function validateCaptcha(){
    var responsec = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    if(responsec.length == 0){

    }else{
        $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "kingSecure/server.php",
                  async: false,
                  data: {
                    "captcha": responsec
                  },
                  success: function(resp) {
                        if(resp == "success") {
                            alert("success");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("fail");
                        }
                  }
                });
    }
        }
```

**PHP**

```
$response = $_POST['captcha'];

$privatekey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$response;
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
$responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

    if($responseData->success){
    echo  'success';
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Len9TYUAAAAAGmBB_lYT7NDXfWlTxWHCs11cWZ8" data-callback="validateCaptcha"></div>
```

Comment: O que aparece da depuração do código no browser?

Comment: Não aparece nada. No network do chrome aparece que o POST está OK, ou seja, foi enviado corretamente.

Comment: Tente imprimir o dump da variavel `$responseData`. Algo como `var_dump($responseData)`, só não coloque dentro do if.

Comment: `object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'success' => boolean false
  public 'challenge_ts' => string '2017-11-05T13:28:45Z' (length=20)
  public 'hostname' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  public 'error-codes' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'invalid-keys' (length=12)`

Comment: Acho que o código está se rompendo, ou o mesmo expirando até enviar a solicitação ao mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Pela mensagem que retornou, deve ser que no Admin do Recaptcha do Google você não tenha o host que está enviando a solicitação, no caso o localhost/127.0.0.1, cadastrado e com uma key. Tente adicionar este host também e utilizar esta nova key.